# Среди чисел найти первое число, большее n

Tags: python

Среди чисел 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ... найти первое число, большее n.
Решить задачу используя циклическую конструкцию for.

Закономерность я уже понял

даны квадраты чисел: 1²; 2²; 3²; 4²; 5²; 6².....

1 - это 1² = 1 * 1 = 1

4 - это 2² = 2 * 2 = 4

9 - это 3² = 3 * 3 = 9

16 - это 4² = 4 * 4 = 16

25 - это 5² = 5 * 5 = 25

36 - это следующее число 6² = 6 * 6 = 36

А как реализовать через for не знаю

вроде так

```
for i in range(N):
  if i * i > N:
    print(i*i)
    break
```

Answer (score 5):

попробуйте так:

```
int(N ** .5 + 1) ** 2
```

Comment: Хоть и не через `for`, но красивое решение!

Comment: @nomnoms12 могу, умею, практикую :)

Comment: @nomnoms12, можно добавить `for _ in range(1):`

Answer (score 3):

1. перебрать все числа от первого и дальше через `for`
2. если число больше `n` - запомнить его и выйти из цикла (`break`)

Answer (score 1):

Перебор:

```py
i = 1
s = 1
while s <= N:
    i += 2
    s += i
print(s)
```

A можно так:

```py
x = 1 
x0 = 0
while x != x0:
    x0 = x
    x = (x + n // x) >> 1
x += 1
print(x*x)
```